# Отправка кнопок через Telegram Api, php guzle

Tags: php, telegram-bot, post, guzzle

Есть задачка получать ответ от клиентов по средством кнопок.
Клиент нажимает на кнопку, бот ловит сообщение и идёт работа.
Есть то что уже работает в теории но не на практике.

```
PostMan (post https://api.telegram.org/botNumero:Token/sendMessage)
```

Тело в постмане

```
{
  "chat_id": номер чата (Личная беседа),
  "text": "Кнопки для товаров",
  "reply_markup": {
    "keyboard": [
      [
        {"text": "Сделать заказ"},
        {"text": "Статус заказ"},
        {"text": "Оформить заказ"}
      ],
      [
        {"text": "Выбрать товар по артикулу"},
        {"text": "Выбрать товар по категории"},
        {"text": "выбрать товар по названию"},
        {"text": "Акции"}
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

При такой обработке всё работает , есть кнопки, после первого нажатия не исчезают, и всё отлично.
Но когда пытаюсь автоматизировать процесс

```
<?php 
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
 $body = '{
            "chat_id": ChatId,// (Личная биседа)
            "text": "Кнопки для товаров",
            "reply_markup": {
                    "keyboard": [
                [
                {"text": "Сделать заказ"},
                {"text": "Статус заказ"},
                {"text": "Оформить заказ"}
                 ],
                 [
                 {"text": "Выбрать товар по артикулу"},
                 {"text": "Выбрать товар по категории"},
                 {"text": "выбрать товар по названию"},
                 {"text": "Акции"}
      ]
    ]
  }
}';
        $json = ["body"=>$body];
        $body = json_decode($body,true);

$client->request("post","https://api.telegram.org/BotNomer:token/sendMessage",$body);
```

возникает ошибка следующего хорактера

```
Client error: `POST https://api.telegram.org/БотНомер:Токен/sendMessage` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: message text is empty"}
```

Будто бы он жалуеться на то что поле 'text' которое идёт после chat_id пустое, но это не так. И вот в чём странность, на постмане всё хорошо отрабатывает на php нет

Comment: посредством кого-чего. слово пишется слитно.

Comment: [Отправка кнопок в telegram bot php](https://nesterenko.site/post/otpravka-knopok-v-telegram-bot-php)

Answer (score 0):

Короче ошибка была в банальном, не было хейдеров в запросе

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
                                             'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']
                                         ]);
```